# Migrating this to the right

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

So, In a dire attempt to move what is seen as the "twitter sidebar" tag here, to the far right next to the lite chat, I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I've tried everything. I mean everything! 
Code is as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="full" lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Skycoding Development - Homepage</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="Images/th.ico" />

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="the-big-picture.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
 </head>

<body>

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Skycoding Development</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <!--The links on the navbar-->
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://www.skycoders.synergize.co/index2.html">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://www.forums.decongesting.net">Forums</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://www.skywiki.22web.org">Wiki</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://www.stickets.synergize.co">tickets</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <!--Everything below here is considered "body". While not being the actuall body.-->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <h1>Skycoding Development</h1>
                <p>Welcome all to the new homepage!</p>
                <!-- FOR 123FLASHCHAT CODE BEGIN --> 
<!-- FlashChats lite code! Do not mess with the impors! --> 
<!-- FOR 123FLASHCHAT CODE BEGIN --> 
<script language="javascript" src="http://127.0.0.1:35555/123flashchat.js"></script> 
<script language="javascript"> 
openSWF("http://127.0.0.1:35555/lite.swf?init_skin=blue&init_fullscreen_text=Go Full :D&init_fullscreen_url=http://127.0.0.1:35555/standard.html", "202", "318" ); 
</script> 
<!-- FOR 123FLASHCHAT CODE END -->
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/Skycoding_Dev" data-widget-id="570094100829847552">Tweets by @Skycoding_Dev</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
</div>
<!-- Messing with the imports can incredibly screw you over!-->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">

</div>
    <!-- /.container -->

    <!-- Dependicys-->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

My site (if neccesery): http://skycoders.synergize.co

Comment: elaborate on your question and the first link (with code) seems to be inaccessible

Comment: Weird, It works for me. Would it potentialy work if I made the CSS code display it on the right of the page? If I put both elements in the same row, But made the col-sm-4 with css, Could I make it go far right? Or is that only with text? @masmrdrr

Comment: One advice: Use relative paths. Replace `http://127.0.0.1:35555/123flashchat.js` with `/123flashchat.js`. The result will be the same but the URL will be more generic.

Comment: Well, That is an external program. So, Yes. It is a external Javascript embed. I didn't want to mess with it. What I was trying to do was combine the twitter timeline and place it next to the lite chat. @Nikolay